# Complexity of an algorithm involving permutations

Tags: permutations, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm looking to figure out the computational complexity of an algorithm in an application I've written. The application computes the answer to a problem that is $\#P$-hard, and the algorithm I'm asking about here is chained multiple times to obtain the result.

Here we consider permutations to be bijections $u:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ (with $0$ excluded) that fix all but finitely many elements, and we represent them as finite lists as follows:

1. Each permutation has at least two elements
2. If $n>2$ is the minimal integer such that $u(i)=i$ for all $i\geq n$, then the list is of length $n-1$.

In our manipulation of permutations in the algorithm they may therefore expand and contract.

Below is python code implementing the algorithm (the relevant function is `elem_sym_perms` and there's a helper `has_bruhat_ascent`).

```
def has_bruhat_ascent(perm,i,j):
    if perm[i]>perm[j]:
        return False
    for p in range(i+1,j):
        if perm[i]<perm[p] and perm[p]<perm[j]:
            return False
    return True 

def elem_sym_perms(orig_perm,p,k):  
    total_list = [(orig_perm,0)]
    up_perm_list = [(orig_perm,1000000000)]
    for pp in range(p):
        perm_list = []
        for up_perm, last in up_perm_list:  
            up_perm2 = [*up_perm,len(up_perm)+1]
            if len(up_perm2) < k + 1:
                up_perm2 += [i+1 for i in range(len(up_perm2),k+2)]
            pos_list = [i for i in range(k) if up_perm2[i] < last]
            for j in range(k,len(up_perm2)):
                if up_perm2[j]>=last:
                    continue
                for i in pos_list:                              
                    if has_bruhat_ascent(up_perm2,i,j):
                        new_perm = [*up_perm2]
                        new_perm[i],new_perm[j] = new_perm[j],new_perm[i]
                        if new_perm[-1] == len(new_perm):
                            new_perm_add = tuple(new_perm[:-1])
                        else:
                            new_perm_add = tuple(new_perm)
                        perm_list += [(new_perm_add,up_perm2[j])]
                        total_list+=[(new_perm_add,pp+1)]
        up_perm_list = perm_list
    return total_list
```

For a description of what this is doing, for a positive integer $k$ we define a relation between permutations $u\xrightarrow{k} w$ where $u\xrightarrow{k} w$ if there exists a sequence of transpositions $t_{a_1b_1},\cdots,t_{a_pb_p}$ for some $0\leq p\leq k$ such that

1. $a_i\leq k<b_i$ for all $i$
2. If $i\neq j$, then $a_i\neq a_j$
3. The number of inversions of $ut_{a_1b_1}\cdots t_{a_ib_i}$ is equal to the number of inversions of $u$ plus $i$ for each $1\leq i\leq p$.
4. $w=ut_{a_1b_1}\cdots t_{a_mb_m}$

An alterative characterization of item $2$ is that $ut_{a_1b_1}\cdots t_{a_ib_i}(a_i)>ut_{a_1b_1}\cdots t_{a_{i+1}b_{i+1}}(a_{i+1})$ for all $i$, which is what is checked in the code because it is faster. We are trying to find all $w$ such that $u\xrightarrow{k} w$ given $u$ and $k$, with the the argument `p` being the maximum inversion difference (where it stops). `has_bruhat_ascent` checks at a pair of positions in the permutation whether there is an inversion there such that swapping the two elements will increase the number of inversions by exactly $1$.

I'm looking to find computational complexity in terms of $k$, $n$ (the length of the array $u$), and as a bonus we could also include $p$, but it is not required.